# A bug or intentional reputation reduction?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

I noticed an issue: when I down voted an answer, my reputation also decreased by 1. I don't understand why? Please help me.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: downvote screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [intended behaviour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and has been forever on SO/SE.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/156248) is a discussion about the issue. This is unlikely to change, but you are welcome to propose a change on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think I will suggest on meta SE a possible measure to avoid downvoting of answers without genuine reason.

Comment: I posted on meta SE. Here's the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312645/396964).

Comment: @kiner_shah Did you actually ask the question on meta SE, or the question was deleted? The link appeared to be non-existent.

Comment: @scaaahu It was closed as duplicate and deleted within minutes. A gold-badge user for the related tag (who "hammered" it) expressed that they have little patience for that particular complaint/proposal because they get it so often (~daily). I expressed that I felt a duplicate chain leading back to a Jeff answer from <2012 may not be an appropriate response to a policy discussion _today_, but received no response.

Comment: @scaaahu, the question was deleted, since it was a duplicate question.